# Get file path from system directory using Flutter web (chrome) to read file content Eg: CSV or Text file

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Package tried: https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Tried the example code implementation shared via GitHub. But the file path is returned as `null` for
***web platform***. Where same implementation in mobile platform return the path as expected.

https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/blob/master/example/lib/src/file_picker_demo.dart

Things aware of:

1. [Path_Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) - Not supported for web
2. [dart-io-library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html) - Not supported for web
3. Open issue in [Flutter Repo](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/45296)

Goal is to read the file from the path and not to upload. Any workaround to achieve this will be helpful.

Flutter channel: beta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the *file_picker* [FAQ](https://github.com/miguelpruivo/flutter_file_picker/wiki/FAQ):

> Paths aren't inaccessible from browsers since those provide fake paths. If you want to create a File instance to upload it somewhere, like FireStorage, you can do so with the bytes directly.

```dart
final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.any, allowMultiple: false);

if (result.files.first != null){
  var fileBytes = result.files.first.bytes;
  var fileName = result.files.first.name;
  print(String.fromCharCodes(fileBytes));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the `String.fromCharCodes(fileBytes)`. Didn't knew that was possible.

Comment: but this is not retuning the path, its for the content

Comment: I have done the exact same thing. Still, i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I have a function for picking image from computer. Might work for you.

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void uploadImage({@required Function(File file) onSelected}) {
  InputElement uploadInput = FileUploadInputElement()..accept = 'image/*';
  uploadInput.click();

  uploadInput.onChange.listen((event) {
    final file = uploadInput.files.first;
    final reader = FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
    reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
      onSelected(file);
    });
  });
}
```